# Where can I download ubuntu with preinstalled packages?

Tags: 15.04, repository

I have an ubuntu ISO image. While installing it, I need to download some packages from ubuntu repository to play media files. Can i get an ubuntu with preloaded package like windows? Windows has some default apps and programs. Where can I get an Ubuntu ISO like that?

Comment: Ubuntu also has "some defaut apps and programs". If your question is only about the packages needed for some media files, you should stick to that. Otherwise, you should state what you want more precisely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)